# facebook login buttons in fancybox load correctly first time only

Tags: facebook, fancybox

I'm adding facebook login buttons to fancybox (version 1.3.4) modals (one for join, one for login).  The facebook buttons all get instantiated when the page loads, but are hidden.  After triggering the fancybox login modal, the facebook buttons get rewritten in the modal and load correctly the first time.  However if you close the modal and then reload it a second or third time, there is no facebook login button.  It's just blank.  When I look at the inline html block
that fancybox based the modal on, the facebook button markup that was generated when the page initially loaded is gone...actually not completely gone, but the button code deep in the iframe is wiped out.

I've seen suggestions to iframe these facebook buttons, so I tried adding an iframe instead of the raw facebook button markup.  Note that I am not using the iframe fancybox type and I can't currently do that.  When I include `<iframe src="/myfacebookbuttonpage"></iframe>` in the modal section, again it loads correctly the first time and then after closing the modal, looking at the source I can see the iframe rewritten as `<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>` and the innards of the iframe are blank.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?  Or is this attempt to include facebook login buttons in fancybox modals completely wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in fancybox v1.3.2+ when using inline iframes.

As a work around, you may edit the fancybox `js` file or apply the workaround in your custom fancybox script.

[Go here for further instructions](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/feec524b4c0199bc)

Comment: we are using fancybox for all of our modals and when I downgraded/upgraded a lot of things broke.  I modified the fancybox source as suggested in the link.  Thanks!